# Move WordPress Network / Multi site to another directory on the same server

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a wordpress network site on `test.mydomain.com` and I also have a simple wordpress site on `mydomain.com`

I want to move my `test.mydomain.com` to `mydomain.com`

I tried by removing the wordpress from `mydomain.com` and moved the networked wordpress from `test.mydomain.com` but I end up breaking my site.

What steps should I take to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to export your files and database from test.mydomain.com. Now open your database sql file and perform search and replace(include test.mydomain.com in search and replace it with mydomain.com). Now create a database and import this updated sql file to a database. Now put all of your files on mydomain.com. Put the information in wp-config.php file and run the mydomain.com URL.

Also while doing this your theme settings and widget will be lost so please remember do not remove the site from test.mydomain.com. Once your site is set up then open wp-admin for  test.mydomain.com and mydomain.com. Now manually update the settings and widget.

Now you are all set.